# Is there a difference in usage between halting and terminating?

Tags: theory

The title says it all: Are halting and terminating synonyms in the context of [computability theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computability_theory)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, it's not called the Terminating Problem; it's called the ["Halting Problem."](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem)

Given that:

```
while(true) { }
```

does not halt, but you could "terminate" it by kicking the power cord out of the wall (or clicking "End Task" in Task Manager), I would say, no, they are not synonyms.

Comment: and how exactly do you predict that someone will pull the power cord out of the socket? ;)

Answer (score 4):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_(computer_science)

> In computer science, a computation is said to diverge if it does not terminate or terminates in an (unobservable) exceptional state. Otherwise it is said to converge.

More specifically relevant to halting,

> In the lambda calculus an expression is divergent if it has no normal form.

So the difference between *halting* -- process does not continue indefinitely -- and *terminating* is that terminating implies returning a normal result.  Not finishing abruptly (with an error or exceptional condition) or wedging itself in a state where no reduction rule applies.

This problem can be illustrated in the λ-calculus extended with booleans and numbers used by [Benjamin Pierce](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/tapl/):

```
(λx.if x then x else x)(1)
```

which will not reduce because it gets stuck at

```
(if 1 then 1 else 1)
```

which does not match any reduction rule since the only rules that apply to `if` are

1. `if true then` *v* `else` *t* → *v*
2. `if false then` *t* `else` *v* → *v*

and `1` is neither `true` nor `false`.